# Summing on all previous values of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data that looks like:

```
Year         Month          Region           Value
1978           1             South             1
1990           1             North             22
1990           2             South             33
1990           2             Mid W             12
1998           1             South             1
1998           1             North             12
1998           2             South             2
1998           3             South             4
1998           1             Mid W             2
.
.

up to
2010
2010
```

My end date is 2010 but I want to sum all **Values** by the **Region** and **Month** by adding all previous year values together.

I don't want just a regular cumulative sum but a **Monthly Cumulative Sum by Region** where Month 1 of Region South is the cumulative Month 1 of Region South of all previous Month 1s before it, etc....

Desired output is something like:

```
Month          Region        Cum_Value
 1             South            2
 2             South            34
 3             South            4
 .
 .
 1             North            34
 2             North            10
 .
 .
 1             MidW              2
 2             MidW              12
```

Comment: use pandas.DataFrame.cumsum

Comment: How can I fit the cumulative sum to my situation without slicing out each month into separate series or frames? I can't just take one column and sum over the last because I want Month 1, 2, 3, 4... to be separately calculated cumulatively with each Region.

Comment: I realize that my question seemed like an easy cumulative sum case so I've changed it.

Comment: provide a bigger sample data and a desired output, otherwise is hard to understand what you need (still seems like a cumsum applied to your group by)

Comment: Provided the desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.groupby` with `pd.DataFrame.cumsum`

```
df1['cumsum'] = df1.groupby(['Month', 'Region'])['Value'].cumsum()
```

Result:

```
   Year  Month Region  Value  cumsum
0  1978      1  South    1.0     1.0
1  1990      1  North   22.0    22.0
2  1990      2  South   33.0    33.0
3  1990      2  Mid W   12.0    12.0
4  1998      1  South    1.0     2.0
5  1998      1  North   12.0    34.0
6  1998      2  South    2.0    35.0
7  1998      3  South    4.0     4.0
8  1998      1  Mid W    2.0     2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solutions that corresponds more with your expected output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1978,1990,1990,1990,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998],
              'Month': [1,1,2,2,1,1,2,3,1],
              'Region': ['South','North','South','Mid West','South','North','South','South','Mid West'],
              'Value' : [1,22,33,12,1,12,2,4,2]})

#DataFrame Result
    Year  Month Region  Value
0   1978    1   South    1
1   1990    1   North    22
2   1990    2   South    33
3   1990    2   Mid West 12
4   1998    1   South    1
5   1998    1   North    12
6   1998    2   South    2
7   1998    3   South    4
8   1998    1   Mid West 2
```

Code to run:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Month','Region']).sum()
df1 = df1.drop('Year',axis=1)
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Month','Region'])

#Final Result

Month   Region  Value
1      Mid West  2
1      North     34
1      South     2
2      Mid West  12
2      South     35
3      South     4
```